# Boost closest distance with json POST request

Tags: solr, solr-boost

I want to boost the closest distance document.  I have constructed the following with help from [the docs](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#geodist_-_The_distance_function):

Post to:
`{{solr-host}}:8983/solr/{{collection}}/select?rows=5`

Body:

```
{
    'query': '{!boost b=recip(geodist(location_ps,-33.92090033,18.42119421),5e-05,2.0,1.0)}*:*',
    'fields': ['title_s', 'score', 'location_ps']
}
```

However, I don't get any `locaiton_ps` in my response.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Please see your query, it should be like this

```
&q={!boost f=recip(geodist(),2,200,20)}canon&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=store&pt=45.15,-93.85&d=50&sort=score desc
```

If you want to get the return the distance then you could add fl=_dist_:geodist() in your request. This will return the distance to you.

Comment: 100% copy paste form the link I posted in my question.  And not enlightening at all.

Comment: What's the problem here

Comment: I'm trying to get the geodist value out via a json post request.  Your answer (which was just copy pasted from the docs) provides no new insight towards that end.

Comment: I just updated that if you want to get the distance in response you need to add \_dist_:geodist() in fl